# Java Swing JScrollPane not scrolling/scalling

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scroll, scale

I am writting a Little prototype which should Display some JLabels with text in it and the complete site should be scrollable.

The Problem which I have is, that the scrollpane is not scrollable and the text is only scalling extremly small.

[image: Scrolling not working]

This is the following code, I already tried working with preferredSize and setSize but nothing worked.

```
public History(Controller c, Model m) {        
            new HistoryHandler(this.history).save();

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.history = new ArrayList<>();

    this.history = new ArrayList<>();
    this.history = new HistoryHandler(this.history).load();

    this.label = new JLabel();
    Container c1 = new Container();
    c1.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.history.size(),1));
    Container c2 = new Container();
    c2.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.history.size(),1));
    Container c3 = new Container();
    c3.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.history.size(),1));
    Container c4 = new Container();
    c4.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.history.size(),1));
    Container c5 = new Container();
    c5.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.history.size(),1));
    Container c6 = new Container();
    c6.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.history.size(),1));

    JLabel c0 = new JLabel();
    c0.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,6));
    for (int i = 0; i < this.history.size(); i++) {
        c1.add(new JLabel(this.history.get(i).getUser()));
        c2.add(new JLabel(this.history.get(i).getDate()));
        c3.add(new JLabel(this.history.get(i).getFilesize()));
        c4.add(new JLabel(this.history.get(i).getFilename()));
        c5.add(new JLabel(this.history.get(i).getMessage()));
        c6.add(new JLabel(""+this.history.get(i).isAccepted()));

    }
    this.label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    c0.add(c2);
    c0.add(c1);
    c0.add(c4);
    c0.add(c3);
    c0.add(c6);
    c0.add(c5);
    this.label.add(c0, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.scroll = new JScrollPane(this.label, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
    this.add(this.scroll);

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: If `Container` refers to java.awt.Container, replace every occurrence of `new Container` with `new JPanel`.  No one should be directly instantiating Container.  You also should use JPanel instead of JLabel to hold multiple components;  JLabel is not meant to have children, even though it’s technically allowed.

Comment: I replaced all `new Container` with `new JPanel` but it is still not working.

Comment: You may find it easier to just place all that data in a JTable, and place that JTable in a JScrollPane.

Comment: Thanks, it works now with JTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the Container and JLabel with a JTable, this is now working correctly.

```
String[] columnNames = {
            this.translation.getTranslation("date"), 
            this.translation.getTranslation("user"),
            this.translation.getTranslation("filename"),
            this.translation.getTranslation("filesize"),
            this.translation.getTranslation("isAccepted"),
            this.translation.getTranslation("message")
    };

    Object[][] data = new Object[this.history.size()][6];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.history.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (j == 0) data[i][j] = this.history.get(i).getDate();
            if (j == 1) data[i][j] = this.history.get(i).getUser();
            if (j == 2) data[i][j] = this.history.get(i).getFilename();
            if (j == 3) data[i][j] = this.history.get(i).getFilesize();
            if (j == 4) data[i][j] = this.history.get(i).isAccepted();
            if (j == 5) data[i][j] = this.history.get(i).getMessage();
        }
    }

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    this.scroll = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
    this.add(this.scroll);
```

Thanks to @VGR for giving me the tipp to replace it with JTable.